# Inbox Functionality with MYSQL

Tags: mysql

So I am writing a simple inbox private message system.

My table schema is as follows:

- messageID
- message
- sender id
- receiver id
- date sent
- read ( 0 = no , 1 = yes)

I am able to show the messages for the user by relating his userID to receiverID. However I also want to show the messages he has sent in the inbox to the user.

For example his inbox should show:

> **Darth Vader** - 3 New messages
>   **Luke**  - 0
>   new messages (0 because either I read
>   all of them OR i sent him the message
>   and he has not replied).

But what i can only come up with is

> **Darth Vader** - 3 New messages.

Can I get any help with how I can accomplish this SQL call?

EDIT: To Clear the Confusion

I am neither Luke or Darth. I have received  3 New messages from darth, and I have sent a message to luke.

EDIT**
Basically I want to be able to make the inbox like how an SMS app would be, where you can see the sms you just sent in a list of sms's by your friends.

Comment: I'm confused. In your example are you Vader or Luke?

Comment: Can we see the query you have already made?  What determines if the message has been replied to or not?

Comment: @Bigstylee Well there is nothing that says if a message has been replied to or not, just if it has been read or not.

@Clint I am neither both, I have received 3 New messages from darth, and I have sent a message to luke.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT users.username, count(messageID) AS unread
FROM users, messages
WHERE messages.senderID=<USER ID>
AND messages.receiverID=users.userID
AND messages.read=0
```

Just to make sure I got this right, this query will show all the users I have sent a message to and count the number of those messages which have not been read.